# How length contraction will work in this case?

Tags: special-relativity, length-contraction

Observer is in a spaceship XYZ. In front of him a rod AB is travelling at velocity V.
Attached to the 2 ends of the rod are light sources(Red and Green) at different heights.
Now these 2 sources emit a flash of light which is recorded in spaceship XYZ.

How the distance between Red and Green light be altered so that the observer in XYZ will record length contraction?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the direction of movement of your rod. If it travels perpendicular (its main axis is perpendicular) to its velocity, there is no length contraction.

On the contrary, if it travels parallel to its velocity, you can apply the standard length-contraction formulae of relativity (cv http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction)

Comment: I meant parallel movement. I'm able to understand the things mathematically. But couldn't see a reason how the distance between 2 flashes of light getting altered due to velocity of the rod.

Comment: On way to see it, which is due to the constancy of the speed of light, whatever the reference frame, is to remark that when, in the rod's reference frame, the light pulses are emitted at the same time (simultaneously), it is not the case in the other reference frames. As I said, time dilation, length contraction and non simultaneity are all consequences of the fact that speed of light is constant. Thus, we you try to measure the moving rod's length by measuring the time between the two flashes, you don't have the same answer as in the rod's reference frame.